# Enumerating necklaces

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Is there a way of enumerating necklaces, in the spirit in which the factorial number system ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system ) can be used to enumerate permutations?

Comment: What's wrong with the formula in Wikipedia?

Comment: @Yuval There is nothing wrong with the wikipedia formula, it only tells how many necklaces there are. For what I am doing I need to list them.

Comment: There's possibly some code in the new part of Knuth's Art of Computer Programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is code here:

http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Recn/Necklaces/